# NodeJS Express Router, pass decoded object between middleware and route?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, authentication, express

I am using Express middleware on all requests to decode a JSON Web Token, and if it is sucessful, attaching a decoded object to the req variable.  I think it is best to just post my code and it will speak for itself.  Basically req.decoded should not be 'Undefined' in my '/user/me/' route because my middleware should be setting that variable when my JSON web token is being decoded after successfully logging in, but it doesn't seem to be working and am not sure why?

**api.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    userSchema = require('../models/User.js'),
    User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    config = require('../../config.js'),
    localStorage = require('localstorage');

module.exports = function(app) {

//Check if user is logged in on every request.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    var authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    jwt.verify(authToken, config.hashKey, function(err, decoded) {
        //decoded seems to be null even after login?
        if (decoded) {
            req.decoded = decoded;
        } 
    });

    next();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) handleError(err);
        if (user) {
            var authToken = jwt.sign({ 
                username: user.username 
                }, config.hashKey, {
                expiresInMinutes: 1440
            });

            localStorage.setItem('token', authToken);
            res.send(user);
        } else {
            res.send('Invalid username or password');
        }
    });
});

app.get('/user/me/', function(req, res) {
    //Outputs Undefined
    console.log('req.decoded=' + req.decoded);
    res.send(req.decoded);
});

app.post('/user/create', function(req,res) {

    var newUser = new User({ username: req.body.username, password: hashedPassword });
    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send('User created');
        } else {
            res.send(err);
        };
    });
});

};
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    require('./app/routes/api.js')(app);

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'triviaattack');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(1337);

console.log('\033[2J');
console.log('Server started!');
```

Comment: You can't use `localstorage` for get the token. It's a server side storage modul. You must send the token to the server from your client if you would like to receive it.

Comment: There are two detailed guide:

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: Thanks gabe, I will check the guides.  I thought localstorage was client side?  Like a cookie?

Comment: This `localstorage` and the `localstorage` in the browser is completely different. They can't 'communicate' with each other.

Comment: Is there a npm module which can interact with the browsers localstorage that you know of?  I guess I will have to attach the token to requests headers?  Anyways thanks again, about to check the guide soon. Hopefully it's what i'm looking for.

Comment: No, there isn't. Yes, you have to attach it in the header or in a parameter if you would like to use it. So it only works with AJAX and WebSocket.

Comment: Have you been able to verify the token is actually stored in the request, specifically the `if (decoded)` line ever returns true?  The question your asking seems to be around storing things in the request and later accessing them, but perhaps it's never stored?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am still new on this stuff, but I have this working in my code).

A couple of things wrong here.

Firstly, the ordering of statements in your server/api is very important. The routes that require a token should come after the app.use that verifies the token.  Routes that do not require a token need to come BEFORE the app.use.  This would include your login route, since it doesn't have a token by definition.

Once you have the ordering fixed, the next problem (pun intended) is that you call next() in your app.use, whether the token gets verified or not.  You need to call next() only if the token gets verified, and send an error message if it doesn't.  In combination with fixing your ordering, this will ensure that your gets/posts that require a token never get processed if the token is invalid.