# Having Issues with Node Express() Transferring Decoded User ID between Middleware and Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I understand that there was a similar question asked to this one but it was never answered clearly ([NodeJS Express Router, pass decoded object between middleware and route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156299/nodejs-express-router-pass-decoded-object-between-middleware-and-route)).

I try to use the VerifyOrdinaryUser function as middleware in the favorites.js route. This function should create a field in the request called req.decoded containing user information. I need to access this user information in favorites.js but it shows up as undefined when I try to log it. Is there an issue regarding asynchronous code? I'm not sure how to fix this. Thank you!

Verify.js:

```
  //verify.js
   var User = require('../models/users');
   var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
   var config = require('../config.js');

    exports.getToken = function (user) {
        return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
            expiresIn: 3600
        });
    };

    exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
        // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
        var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        // decode token
        if (token) {
            // verifies secret and checks exp
            jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                    err.status = 401;
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    req.params.id = req.decoded._doc_id;
                    next();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // if there is no token
            // return an error
            var err = new Error('No token provided!');
            err.status = 403;
            return next(err);
        }
    };

    exports.verifyAdmin = function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.decoded._doc.admin == false) {
            next();
        } else {
            // if the user is not admin
            // return an error
            var err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
            err.status = 403;
            return next(err);
        }

    };
```

Favorites.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/users');
var Favorite = require('../models/favorites');
var Verify = require('./verify');

router.get('/', Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(res, req, next){
  console.log(req.decoded);
});
```

App.js: (not necessary to look at)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var dishes = require('./routes/dishes');
var favorites = require('./routes/favorites');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

var User = require('./models/users');
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/dishes', dishes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/favorites', favorites);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an issue regarding asynchronous code?

No. You call next() in callback, so next middleware is called when async stuff is done.

Problem is because you messed up order of arguments. Try replace `function(res, req, next)` with 
`function(req, res, next)`.

Comment: You are right! I can't believe I missed that and thank you very much for the help.

Comment: nice answer @Jakub Kutreba Thanks.